# #foo:active alternative in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Does someone knows whats the alternative for the :active in qt? When a button is selected, but with tab or arrow keys ?

I've tried this :

```
#calcButton:active{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

but does not work

Comment: Do you mean something like `checked`? I didn't understand what you want.

Comment: In QML or native Qt?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R these are buttons actually, and i want them to have a red bg when selectex with tab or arrows (the program is going to be used on an small embedded device)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Native QT

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) suggests `#calcButton[focus=true]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all changed the `focuspolicy` of buttons to **TabFocus**:

[image]

**then set this stylesheet :**

```
QPushButton::focus {color:red;}
```

**output by press Tab button:**

[image]